# Error trying install laravel (valet command not found)

Tags: laravel

I am currently trying to install laravel, and following [this tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/valet#installation) :

I already installed brew, composer and php, but when I try to install valet I get the following error : `valet: command not found`.

I already changed my path (twice, I think), because when I echo path I get:
`c/Users/Tiago/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/snap/bin:/home/tiago/.composer/vendor/bin`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valet is for MacOS, seems like you are using windows.

Use [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead) instead.